# ActiveMQ via REST: High throughput Jetty configuration

Tags: performance, jetty, activemq-classic

i want to send Messages to ActiveMQ via HTTP Requests. I created my own Servlet (the default servlet isn't that good). Unfortunately my Server only handles 400 Requests per second.

Is there a configuration i have to do so jetty can handle more?

I'm running on an 8 core maschine so more requests should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi, I am looking almost same. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
Did you configure the jetty thread pool high enough to concurrently handle your requests?

Or is the CPU utilization of the JVM at 100% at runtime? If yes, you might want to run some Java profiler and find out where most of the time is being spent.

Comment: I configured the threadpool with the activemq jetty.xml file. `<bean id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start"
        destroy-method="stop">

                <property name="threadPool">
                        <bean id="pool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
                                <property name="minThreads" value="1000" />
                                <property name="maxThreads" value="1000"/>
                        </bean>
                </property>` and the the cpu is mostly idling.