# Poor performance of ActiveMQ rest message services?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am try to publish message using restful post request but not able to publish more then 200 msg/sec
And my CPU utilization is above 90% and I do load test using jmeter.
 my instance type of ActiveMQ  M1.large on amazon EC2 ,
I also configure for performance change like thread  size 
I had followed following like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487851/activemq-via-rest-high-throughput-jetty-configuration
http://www.pepperdust.org/?p=150

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms5G" 

export ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY ="-Xms5G"

ulimit -n 65000
```

Then also not able to publish more then 200 msg/sec

Comment: Please could you guide me on this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/integration-of-restful-wvb-service-with-activemq

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are lots of variables here.
Just made a simple jmeter test on my vanilla activemq installation locally on my laptop.

Jmeter:
10 threads, 
~5K text file / message.

= ~370 persistent msg / sec.

What's your settings in jmeter? Are you considering using JMS instead?

Comment: i am using rest post request on ActiveMQ using url http://localhost:8161/demo/message/anand?readTimeout=1000&type=queue